# C BZ2_bzDecompress way slower than bzip2 command

Tags: c, performance, bzip2

I'm using mmap/read + BZ2_bzDecompress to sequentially decompress a large file (29GB). This is done because I need to parse the uncompressed xml data, but only need small bits of it, and it seemed like it would be way more efficient to do this sequentially than to uncompress the whole file (400GB uncompressed) and then parse it. Interestingly already the decompression part is extremely slow - while the shell command bzip2 is able to do a bit more than 52MB per second (used several runs of `timeout 10 bzip2 -c -k -d input.bz2 > output` and divided produced filesize by 10), my program is able to do not even 2MB/s, slowing down after a few seconds to 1.2MB/s

The file I'm trying to process uses multiple bz2 streams, so I'm checking `BZ2_bzDecompress` for `BZ_STREAM_END`, and if it occurs, use `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd( strm );` and `BZ2_bzDecompressInit( strm, 0, 0 )` to restart with the next stream, in case the file hasn't been completely processed. I also tried without `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd` but that didn't change anything (and I can't really see in the documentation how one should handle multiple streams correctly)

The file is being mmap'ed before, where I also tried different combinations of flags, currently `MAP_RDONLY`, `MAP_PRIVATE` with madvise to `MADV_SEQUENTIAL | MADV_WILLNEED | MADV_HUGEPAGE` (I'm checking return value, and madvise does not report any problems, and I'm on a linux kernel 3.2x debian setup which has hugepage support)

When profiling I made sure that other than some counters for measuring speed and a printf which was limited to once every n iterations, nothing else was run. Also this is on a modern multicore server processor where all other cores where idle, and it's bare metal, not virtualized.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong / do to improve performance?

Update: Thanks to James Chong's suggestion I tried "swapping" `mmap()` with `read()`, and the speed is still the same. So it seems `mmap()` is not the problem (either that, or `mmap()` and `read()` share an underlying problem)

Update 2: Thinking that maybe the malloc/free calls done in bzDecompressInit/bzDecompressEnd would be the cause, I set bzalloc/bzfree of the bz_stream struct to a custom implementation which only allocates memory the first time and does not free it unless a flag is set (passed by the opaque parameter = strm.opaque). It works perfectly fine, but again the speed did not increase.

Update 3: I also tried fread() instead of read() now, and still the speed stays the same. Also tried different amount of read bytes and decompressed-data-buffer sizes - no change.

Update 4: Reading speed is definitely not an issue, as I've been able to achieve speeds close to about 120MB/s in sequential reading using just mmap().

Comment: I'd try reading in the file "manually" (i.e. `read()`), to see if it's any issue with `mmap`. Also could it be that you're linking with a debug version of the bz2 library?

Comment: @JamesChong I will try the read() approach and report back - I'm using the debian provided packages libbz2 (+ libbz2-dev for the header file), so it shouldn't be a debug version - or at least, is should be the same version bzip2 command is using, so it should not be the problem.

Comment: @JamesChong After much work I got the whole thing working using read()  (because I don't have to deal with remaining data offsets with mmap, the read() code is slightly more complex), but there is no performance difference when using read().

Comment: Mysterious :( unfortunately I don't have the liberty of time to benchmark the bz2 library for myself yet. If I may offer one last suggestion: try compiling and statically linking with the latest version from `bzip.org`, failing which, I'll refrain from further comment until I get a chance to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping, mmap flags have with them little to do. If bzip2 is slow, it is not because of the file I/O.

I think your libbz2 wasn't fully optimized. Recompile it with the most brutal gcc flags which you can imagine.

My second idea were if there is some ELF linking overhead. In this case the problem will disappear if you link in bz2 statically. (After that you will be able to think how to make this fast with dynamically loaded libbz2).

**Important extension from the future:**
Libbz2 *must* be reentrant, thread-safe and position-independent. This means various C flags to be compiled with, and these flags don't have a good effect to performance (although they produce much faster code). In an extrem case I could even imagine a 5-10-times slow, compared to the single-threaded, non-PIC, non-reentrant version.